# rsyslog config does not write to file

Tags: rhel, syslog, rsyslog

I just installed rsyslog on rhel8. So the /etc/rsyslog.conf file is stock. Here's my custom config:

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/10-remote.conf
module(load="imudp")

ruleset(name="remote_udp"){
    local5.info;local7.debug;local7.info action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/router_temp/v8temp.log" FileCreateMode="0644") & stop
}

input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="remote_udp")
```

I can see traffic coming in using

```
tcpdump -i ens224 udp port 514
```

I'm getting messages in the format of:

```
15:26:21.054704 IP testrouter.notell.net.syslog > myserver.notell.net.syslog: SYSLOG local7.info, length: 171
```

Nothing is being printed to /var/log/router_temp/v8temp.log. What am I missing here?

I do get messages however, if I run logger from another server:

```
logger -p local5.info -n myserver.notell.net -P 514 -d "sending over udp from another server"
```

Answer (score 0):

My system was permitting traffic from a private network, 514/udp and 514/tcp. When I switched to public 514/udp 514/tcp, I started receiving logs.